# facing error while stencil bundle command

Tags: bigcommerce, node-sass

currently i update my node and npm version for stencil bigcommerce when i make bundle for my old project i'm facing this type of problem. can anyone solve my this issue?

## Error: No input specified: provide a file name or a source string to process

---------WARNING---------
We are currently in the process of deprecating node-sass fork https://github.com/bigcommerce-labs/node-sass
Your scss files were compiled using latest node-sass version https://github.com/sass/node-sass
This error might indicate that your scss file is not compatible with it.
There is still an option to compile scss file old fork by using --use-old-node-sass-fork.
But note, that this will lead to 500 error in production in near future.
---------WARNING---------

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to resolve the SCSS errors in your files that are causing a failure.

However, a quick solution may be to roll back your stencil version. Try `npm install -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli@3.12` and then try bundling your theme. Note: you will need to be on Node v12 for this.

Comment: this command throw a error.  Error:-  npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\User14\AppData\Roaming\npm\stencil-bundle.cmd
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Users\User14\AppData\Roaming\npm\stencil-bundle.cmd: is outside C:\Users\User14\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\User14\AppData\Roaming\npm\stencil-bundle.cmd
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User14\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-30T11_44_51_359Z-debug.log

Comment: even when i try stencil start its show this- /c/Users/User14/AppData/Roaming/npm/stencil: line 12: node: command not found

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error, their were no node or big commerce CLI version issue, I had to just upgrade my bootstrap version in Base.html file and the error was solved.